# How to ignore directories with same name as file while hiding extentions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, apache2.4

I have a directory and a file with the same name, example:

foo.html

foo/

My .htaccess file is set up to hide the file extensions in the address bar, so when I request www.example.com/foo it should display the foo.html file. However, since there is a directory with the same name - the foo.html file is not displayed and the directory is shown instead like www.examplecom/foo/

How can I ensure that files take precedence over directories with the same name? I'v been googling for hours and have not found a working solution. I've tried disabling DirectorySlash with no luck.

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

Running Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server

Answer (score 1):

Replace your rule with:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

You don't need `DirectorySlash Off` line as well.

Comment: I like what you did in the `RewriteCond`—masterful syntax, +1 :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have done as you have said but unfortunately I am getting the same results, infact now none of my urls are working, perhaps there is a small error somewhere?

Comment: There is no error in these rules but other rules might in conflict. Can you post your complete .htaccess in your question so that I can investigate.

Comment: I'm actually just using my apache2.conf file instead of .htaccess


`<Directory /var/www/>
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted


     RewriteEngine On


 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]

</Directory>`

Comment: For testing purpose place these rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` instead of Apache config. You may need to enable `.htaccess` if it is not already enabled.